# Mailgun changed links in my email

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, mailgun

I'm using the php framework Laravel to send emails with mailgun to a certain list. The emails get delivered all the links got changed to email.mg.mydomain/c/.... for some reason everything is fine in the view i sent. After sending some emails there were alot of drops and bounces from mailgun so my domain got disabled - could this be the reason? I use open and click tracking.

Here is my code for sending

```
$client = new \Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client();

$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-notmyrealkey', $client);
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
                'from' => 'Sender <news@domain.com>',
                'to' =>  $mail ,
                'subject' => 'Sender',
                'html' => view('some_view'),
            ));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is exactly what click tracking does - it re-writes the URLs for each outgoing email so that Mailgun can track independent clicks and associate them with a specific email. This is why the Domain Verification & DNS part of the Mailgun setup on your domain involved setting up the "email." sub-domain as a CNAME pointing to mailgun.org.